# Access value from multidimensional Hash rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have to access the id and other important information of each operator.
The structure of given data is:

```
{:items=>
  [{:id=>"868f136b-ec4e-4794-a3a9-a70d4b83ab38",
    :clientId=>"e92ca89f-8524-451a-9346-666d6ff39329",
    :name=>"allergy_type_display",
    :description=>nil,
    :mnemonic=>"allergy_type_display",
    :columnType=>"dropdown",
    :entityId=>"d96804c4-c815-4d65-891f-b5e5c418587e",
    :createdAt=>"2019-11-27T05:01:34.000Z",
    :updatedAt=>"2019-11-27T05:01:34.000Z",
    :display=>true,
    :fallbackId=>nil,
    :conceptDisplay=>false,
    :businessName=>nil,
    :operators=>
     [{:id=>"15e8c619-7b5b-4612-b2e9-7a17112eceb9",
       :mnemonic=>"gte",
       :description=>"Greater than Equals to",
       :createdAt=>"2019-07-01T13:10:15.000Z",
       :updatedAt=>"2019-07-01T13:10:15.000Z",
       :clientId=>nil},
      {:id=>"38888bef-5442-4c72-b88e-44f4fd3e5614",
       :mnemonic=>"eq",
       :description=>"Equals To",
       :createdAt=>"2019-06-26T09:30:15.000Z",
       :updatedAt=>"2019-07-06T04:14:59.000Z",
       :clientId=>nil},
      {:id=>"4fd6ce17-10d3-42a3-8e4e-24773360db5d",
       :mnemonic=>"ne",
       :description=>"Not Equals To",
       :createdAt=>"2019-06-26T09:19:03.000Z",
       :updatedAt=>"2019-07-06T04:58:11.000Z",
       :clientId=>nil},
      {:id=>"b252eac5-f5dc-41ce-bc49-2364f5a73bb1",
       :mnemonic=>"lte",
       :description=>"Less than Equals to",
       :createdAt=>"2019-07-01T13:10:15.000Z",
       :updatedAt=>"2019-07-01T13:10:15.000Z",
       :clientId=>nil}]}]}
```

Here I am not able to access the id of each operator. All these values I have stored in instance variable **@ans**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [dig](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/dig) and [pluck](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) methods

```rb
@ans.dig(:items, 0, :operators)&.pluck(:id)
```

Or if you don't use Rails

```rb
@ans.dig(:items, 0, :operators)&.map { |el| el[:id] }
```

Or if you use old ruby which doesn't support safe navigation and `dig` method, you can use [try](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/Object/try) method:

```rb
@ans[:items].try(:[], 0).try(:[], :operators).try(:map) { |h| h[:id] }
```

```rb
# output

["15e8c619-7b5b-4612-b2e9-7a17112eceb9", "38888bef-5442-4c72-b88e-44f4fd3e5614", "4fd6ce17-10d3-42a3-8e4e-24773360db5d", "b252eac5-f5dc-41ce-bc49-2364f5a73bb1"]
```

Comment: Another option is the old-school `ans[:items][0][:operators].pluck(:id)`. If the data is malformed, this (as opposed to the use of `dig`) will raise an exception, which would be useful in locating the problem. Note the structure of the data is believed to be known. I don't especially dig `dig`.